# QTableView setSortingEnabled is forcing sortBycolumn

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

I am using a `QTableView` and when I enable sorting using the [`setSortingEnabled`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#sortingEnabled-prop) there is an immediate call to the `sortByColumn()`, but I do not want this as this sorts my table by default 1st column.

- I want just to enable sorting and not to force sorting when enabling
- Is there a way to avoid the `sortByColumn()` call?
- Or how can I overwrite the `sortByColumn()` method and prevent the sorting there?

Comment: Why do not you call that function when you want it to be ordered and not before?

Comment: @eyllanesc as far as I have gathered to enable sorting for the QTableView we need to set the  setSortingEnabled to true I am doing this in my init function when setting up the model/view/delegates for my view.

Comment: @eyllanesc it would be helpful if you can suggest where can I set the flag setSortingEnabled so that I am able to do sorting by clicking on column headers.

Comment: Okay, I got it, are you using Qt4 or Qt5?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using Qt5.9

Comment: I just tried and even if I enabled the property sortingEnabled to True the table is not sorted, I find it strange what it says.

Comment: @eyllanesc can you try to use a model derived from QAbstractTableModel , and then try the same, I found this answer useful : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/467-QTableView-sorting for your issue

Comment: You must provide a MVCE, you could share a project to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible work-around for the above problem as has been suggestted in the Qt Forums where I asked the similar question https://forum.qt.io/topic/84870/qtableview-setsortingenabled-forcing-sortbycolumn

Answer (score 0):

You could set default sorting column to -1 by [QHeaderView::setSortIndicator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSortIndicator) like this

```
yourTableView->horizontalHeader()->setSortIndicator(-1, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

before running

```
yourTableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

because [QTableView::setSortingEnabled](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#sortingEnabled-prop) uses [QHeaderView::sortIndicatorOrder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sortIndicatorOrder) and [QHeaderView::sortIndicatorSection](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#sortIndicatorSection) to identify by which column should model be sorted.

Note that documentation of [QHeaderView::setSortIndicator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSortIndicator) tells that not all models support setting sort column to -1 and may even crash in this case.